# How to send client component data to server component with supported compose pattern in NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How to send client component data to server component by following example

- Below Component is a **Client Component**
- The Child Component or `{children}` will be a **Server Component**

```
<ClientComponent>
 <ServerComponent/>
</ClientComponent>
```

##### Problem

- I need to send `count` & `setCount` to that **Server Component**.
- I can't do `count` & `setCount` to it's parent cause that is an Server Component.

I tried a lot in different way & search in docs but failed.

```js
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      {children}
    </>
  )
```

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Well, any other pattern to achieve this?

Comment: Make the server components client components. Look into what "server components" and "client components" really are. 

Server components only get rendered on the server. Think of them as traditional web dev static HTML templates that get rendered on the server and passed to the browser. Therefore, they obviously can't be interactive as they have been passed off and are no longer interactive.